# How do I simplify the function below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui

I was able to achieve a content switcher with the block of code below but I'm looking for a way to simplify it. There are up to 10 or more topics to switch between, how do I simplify it so that the code wouldn't be too large, instead of having a block of code per DIV.

```
jQuery(document) .ready(function () {
    $('.topic-intro:not(:nth-of-type(1))') .hide();
    $('#mid-nav-in ul li:nth-of-type(1)') .addClass('active');
    $('#mid-nav-in ul li a:nth-of-type(1)') .click(function () {
        $('.topic-intro:not(:nth-of-type(1))') .hide();
        $('.topic-intro:nth-of-type(1)') .show();
        $('#mid-nav-in ul li:not(:nth-of-type(1))') .removeClass('active');
        $('#mid-nav-in ul li:nth-of-type(1)') .addClass('active');
    });
});
jQuery(document) .ready(function () {
    $('#mid-nav-in ul li:nth-of-type(2) a') .click(function () {
        $('.topic-intro:not(:nth-of-type(2))') .hide();
        $('.topic-intro:nth-of-type(2)') .show();
        $('#mid-nav-in ul li:nth-of-type(2)') .addClass('active');
        $('#mid-nav-in ul li:not(:nth-of-type(2))') .removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you maybe make a jsfiddle with a simplified example? This is hard to decode without the associated markup to go with the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from your code that you are using the links in `#mid-nav-in` to show the corresponding `.topic-intro` and then hiding all others. It also appears that the code depends on the `.topic-intro` elements being in the same order as the links in the `#mid-nav-in`. If this is the case something like to following would work:

```
$('#mid-nav-in li a').on('click', function(){
    // Remove 'active' Class from all <li/>
    $('#mid-nav-in li').removeClass('active');

    // Add 'active' Class to <li/> of Clicked Link
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

    // Hide All .topic-intro elements
    $('.topic-intro').hide();

    // Show .topic-intro element at the Same index of Clicked Link
    $('.topic-intro').eq($(this).closest('li').index()).show();

    return false; // prevent default action 
});

// Automatically Select the First Link
$('#mid-nav-in li a').eq(0).trigger('click');
```

Here is a fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6hd97/2/

I hope this helps.